# Google app engine JPA onetomany relationship add fail with IllegalArgumentException: String over 500 charcters

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, one-to-many

It was a old project on GAE one year ago. It works pretty well at that time. Recently I tried to work on this project again, but it doesn't work well now. I figured out what the problem is, but I don't know how to solve it.

Add new user is ok. but when I trying to add image of a user, the image file itself stored in blobstore succesfully but the record entity `Image`could not be persist.

It seems that gae couldn't set the value of the `image` field in User table and come up with a strange error which says String too long. It probably related to LAZY loading stuff.

I would be appercaite if you could help me out.

Here is my entities and the code where the error happen.
OnetoMany relationship in User entity:

```
    @Entity
    public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    Integer userid;

    String username;

    String password;

    String email;

    @OneToMany()
    Collection<Image> images;

    // getter and setter....
    }
```

Image Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Image {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    Integer imageid;

    private String name;

    // full path of blobstore
    private String path;

    private Date uploadtime;


}
```

Where the error occur:

```
    //ImageService.java/uploadImage
    user = userDao.findUser(userid);
    Collection<Image> images = user.getImages();
    images.add(image); // Exception occurs here
    user.setImages(images);
    userDao.update(user);
```

Stack Trace:

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path: String properties must be 500 characters or less.  Instead, use com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text, which can store strings of any length.
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedSingleValue(DataTypeUtils.java:242)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:207)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:173)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:148)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PropertyContainer.setProperty(PropertyContainer.java:101)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.setEntityProperty(EntityUtils.java:169)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.StoreFieldManager.storeFieldInEntity(StoreFieldManager.java:245)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.StoreFieldManager.storeStringField(StoreFieldManager.java:168)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.providedStringField(AbstractStateManager.java:1438)
    at com.nhm.persistence.entity.Image.jdoProvideField(Image.java)
    at com.nhm.persistence.entity.Image.jdoProvideFields(Image.java)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.provideFields(AbstractStateManager.java:1520)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjectsInternal(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:232)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:214)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2371)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.makePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2347)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1798)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1892)
    at org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.SCOUtils.validateObjectForWriting(SCOUtils.java:1501)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.AbstractFKStore.validateElementForWriting(AbstractFKStore.java:383)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.validateElementForWriting(FKListStore.java:1029)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.internalAdd(FKListStore.java:193)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.scostore.FKListStore.addAll(FKListStore.java:114)
    at org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.backed.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:727)
    at org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.backed.ArrayList.initialise(ArrayList.java:161)
    at org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.SCOUtils.createSCOWrapper(SCOUtils.java:249)
    at org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.SCOUtils.newSCOInstance(SCOUtils.java:140)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.wrapSCOField(JDOStateManager.java:2225)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.setObjectField(AbstractStateManager.java:2051)
    at com.nhm.persistence.entity.User.jdoSetimages(User.java)
    at com.nhm.persistence.entity.User.setImages(User.java:131)
    at com.nhm.web.service.ImageService.uploadImage(ImageService.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:43)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:480)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:487)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:774)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:751)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:342)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:334)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:484)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store Strings longer than 500 Unicode characters you need to use [`Text`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Text) instead. See [Datastore Properties & Value Types](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Properties_and_Value_Types).

Comment: Yes, but actully I am not gonna store any string directly, i just want to add an Image entity to the Image collect in User class. Even it is because of string too long. But I cannot do anything about it, because I can't set how the how foreign key is gemerated in datastore.

Comment: if you aren't going to store a String directly, why is it trying to store a String then ... such as Image.name, Image.path fields ? they are all persistent by default. One of them is over 500 in length, and if you don't want to persist them then you mark as @NotPersistent

Comment: Yes, I do, but one year ago. Those field could be persist. I don't think the image name will be over 500. Maybe the file path can be over 500. I will check it out.